# How to check whether data existed or not in waterline of sails

Tags: sails.js

I desire to create application with parameters name, email of Candidate, title of Job, and description, salary and position of JobDetail.
Here are my code

```
create: async function (req, res) {
try {
  let { name, email, title, description, salary, position } = req.allParams();
  if (!name) {
    return res.badRequest('name is required');
  }
  if (!email) {
    return res.badRequest('email is required');
  }
  if (!salary) {
    return res.badRequest('salary is required');
  }
  //check job exist
  const checkExistence = await Job.findOne({
    title: title
  });
  if (!checkExistence) {
    return res.badRequest('Job does not exist!!!');
  }
  return res.ok('Ok!!!');
} catch (error) {
  res.serverError(error);
}
```

}

I'm stuck with checking whether the Job model possessed the input job or not?
I just applied findOne() or find() to check the existence, but I feel quite the solution is not best practice.
I am fresh to Sails. Hope you guys to help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation of request parameters in the `backend` is not a good practice. You should do it in the `frontend`. Anyway you can use above code to check the existence of a job title. Instead you can use traditional `node.js` callbacks for checking existence of a job title as below.

```
Job.findOne({ title: title}).exec(function(err, result){
    if (err) { 
        return res.send({ message: 'error'}); 
    }
    else if (!result) {
        return res.send({ message: 'job does not exists'});
    }
    return res.send({ message: 'success'});
});
```